# IONIC 4 InAppBrowser hidden until it finishes loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser

I am using InAppBrowser IONIC 4 to open a URL from my APP. My problem is that a blank screen appears while the page loads.

How can I give a "loading page" message? There is a way to avoid the blank page

Thank you

This is my code currently.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}

    public reportes() {
    var target = "_blank";
    const browser =this.iab.create('google.com.mx',target,{
      location: 'no',zoom: 'no',
    });

  }  

}
```

Comment: Did any answer work for you? If yes, do consider accepting/upvoting them. Else let us know how we can change them to fit your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

   loaderToShow: any;

  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController
  ) {
  }

  showLoader() {
    this.loaderToShow = this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'This Loader will Not AutoHide'
    }).then((res) => {
      res.present();

      res.onDidDismiss().then((dis) => {
        console.log('Loading dismissed!');
      });
    });
    this.hideLoader();
  }

  hideLoader() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loadingController.dismiss();
    }, 4000);
  }

}
```

Comment: And where would you place to open the web?

Comment: you can call showLoader() method before the reportes() method